# How to import Interface into angular component from models

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

When i try to access data of an interface into a component it gives error:
**error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Contacts'**

and when i try to import that interface it says:
**error TS2307: Cannot find module '../models/contacts'**.

I used an Interface(Contacts) to make some data available for a component(contact-list.component.ts)

Please tell me what I am doing wrong by looking at below code snippets. 
I am stuck with this Hands on from last two days, pls help

```
 ----------model contacts.ts------------
 export interface Contacts {
  contactsList: Contact[];
}

export interface Contact {
id: number;
name: string;
city: string;
}

 -----------app.module.ts----------------
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from 'src/app/services/contact.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactListComponent } from './components/contact-list/contact- 
list.component';

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   ContactListComponent
   ],
  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
],
   providers: [ContactService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }




---------------contact-list.component.ts---------------

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from 'src/app/services/contact.service';
import { Contacts } from '../models/contacts';

@Component({
selector: 'app-contact-list',
templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./contact-list.component.css']
})
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {

  contacts;
  constructor(
  private contactService: ContactService
  ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe((data: Contacts) => {
     this.contacts = data ? data.contactsList : [];
  });
 }

}
 --------------------contact.service.ts--------------------
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Contacts } from '../models/contacts';
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ContactService {

contacts = {
  'contactsList': [
      {'id': 1, 'name': 'Rajesh', 'city': 'bangalore'},
      {'id': 2, 'name': 'Aarjith', 'city': 'london'},
      {'id': 3, 'name': 'Anjan', 'city': 'california'},
      {'id': 4, 'name': 'David', 'city': 'delhi'}
    ]
 };
constructor(
) { }

getContacts(): Observable<Contacts> {
    return of(this.contacts);
   }
}
```

expected output:
Rajesh
Aarjith
Anjan
David

Comment: Using `import { Contacts } from '../models/contacts';` in `contact-list.component.ts` works just fine.

Comment: thats the problem `import { Contacts } from '../models/contacts';` works with _contact.service.ts_ but not with _contact-list.component.ts_

Comment: can you make a stackblitz with a minimal demo?

Comment: Your [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kho5dj) is a mess. Many import statements are wrong.

Comment: sure @IftifarTaz  here is a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjscuu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontact-list%2Fcontact-list.component.ts)

Comment: In our [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjscuu) in `app.module.ts` import statement for `ContactService` is wrong. Import it like you do in `contact-list.component.ts`

Comment: I tried but now it says cannot find src, even if it is there

Comment: It will work if you are in your local machine. Looks like stackblitz does not support import from root. By the way import `Contacts ` from `'../models/contact'` not `'../models/contacts'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hands-on must be from fresco play 
I faced the same issue, there is nothing wrong in your code as if you try importing contacts like  `import { Contacts } from '../models/contacts';`  it will not recognize contacts and if you try importing like  `import { Contacts } from 'src/app/models/contacts';` then online ide will create problem. you must have passed the hands on with the submission even with the error. and if you try it with local ide it will work fine.

Comment: yes u are right, I passed the hands-on without even resolving above problem. but are you damn sure that there is nothing wrong with my solution

Comment: not damn sure but sure because i found nothing on google about it

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { dataService } from '../service/data.service';

interface UserInfo {
    id: number;
    userName: string;
    role: string;
    sourceName: string
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-patient-view',
    templateUrl: './patient-view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./patient-view.component.css']
})

export class PatientViewComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService, private http: HttpClient, public dtService: dataService, private router: Router, private dialog: MatDialog) { }
    SourceNameSelector(oneSourceName) {
        this.http.get('/setSelectedSource/' + oneSourceName.id).subscribe(data => {
            ///code for return the source
            this.dtService.getUserDetails = {
                id: data['ID'],
                userName: data['USERNAME'],
                role: data['role'],
                sourceName: data['sourceName']
            };
        });
    }
}
```

this only tells you how to use interface in an .ts file

Answer (score 0):

I reckon, you missing to reference the `Contacts` interface within the `contact-list.component.ts` file. That could be an issue.

Comment: I tried 
    import { Contacts } from '../models/contacts';
but it's not working
btw thnks for having look
and thnks if you could find something wrong other than this

Comment: @Krishnakant, can you produce the error on using stackblitz.com, so that it's easy to debug?

Comment: yeah @rc.adhikari , here is [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjscuu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontact-list%2Fcontact-list.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Please use full path:

```
import { Contacts } from 'src/app/models/contacts';
```